# Change language texMemo

Tags: languages

I am writing a letter, but want to change the language to Dutch. However, i can't figure out how to get the "To", "From", "Subject" and "Date" to change to Dutch. It should be something like "Naar", "Van", "Onderwerp" and "Datum".

[image: Text being in English]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{texMemo}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx, lipsum}

\memoto{Person}
\memofrom{Person}
\memosubject{Subject}
\memodate{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values are hardcoded in the class. You can either change them yourself (by editing the `texMemo.cls` file line 56-59) or use the `etoolbox` package to modify the values dynamically.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{texMemo}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx, lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\makememotitle}{To:}{Aan:}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makememotitle}{From:}{Van:}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makememotitle}{Subject:}{Onderwerp:}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makememotitle}{Date:}{Datum:}{}{}

\memoto{Person}
\memofrom{Person}
\memosubject{Subject}
\memodate{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[]

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Result with language changed]